# Is there any way to make PHP Variable from HTML Attributes value

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, attributes

[image]

Is there any way   to make write PHP Variable from id value (123).

thanks...

Comment: Send the value of the id field to your PHP Script...

Comment: but how. If possible please explain...

Comment: It looks like the id is hardcoded to the PHP file, why not hardcode it into a variable too? What is your use-case, and how is JavaScript related to the question? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming